# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, accounting

I am struggling to figure out why this code isn't compiling. the exact error im getting is:

```
ERROR at line 82:
ORA-06550: line 82, column 4: 
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the 
following: 
( begin case declare end exit for goto if loop mod null 
pragma raise return select update while with <an identifier> 
<a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> << 
continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback 
savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge
```

What I'm trying to do is taken in a bunch of transactions from a temporary table "new_Transactions", and add them into another couple tables, "Account", "Transaction_History" and "Transaction_Detail". The new_transaction table can have multiple debits and credits for each transaction, so the nested should read all of the transactions into the file.

Ive been struggling to figure out where the error is for quite a while, I'll admit that SQL isnt my strong point, so if there are glaringly terrible errors please let me know.

```
DECLARE 
r_transaction NEW_TRANSACTIONS%ROWTYPE;
CURSOR c_trans_no IS
SELECT *
INTO r_transaction
FROM new_transactions
ORDER BY transaction_no;

v_credit_check  NEW_TRANSACTIONS.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT%TYPE;
v_debit_check   NEW_TRANSACTIONS.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT%TYPE;


BEGIN

FOR r_transaction IN C_trans_no LOOP
    v_debit_check:=0;
    v_credit_check:=0;
            DECLARE
                r_test NEW_TRANSACTIONS%ROWTYPE;
                CURSOR c_new_trans IS
                SELECT *
                INTO r_test
                FROM new_transactions
                WHERE   transaction_no = r_transaction.transaction_no;

                    BEGIN
                        FOR r_test IN c_new_trans LOOP
                        DECLARE
                        v_number  NUMBER(8,2);
                        rec_account ACCOUNT%ROWTYPE;
                        BEGIN
                        SELECT *
                        INTO rec_account
                        FROM ACCOUNT
                        WHERE account_no = r_test.account_no;

                        INSERT INTO TRANSACTION_HISTORY(transaction_no, transaction_date, description)
                        VALUES (r_test.transaction_no, r_test.transaction_date, r_test.description);
                        INSERT INTO TRANSACTION_DETAIL(account_no, transaction_no, transaction_type, transaction_amount)
                        VALUES (r_test.account_no, r_test.transaction_no, r_test.transaction_type, r_test.transaction_amount);

                        IF(r_test.transaction_type = 'D') THEN
                            v_debit_check := v_debit_check + r_test.transaction_amount;
                            CASE rec_account.account_type_code
                                WHEN  'A' THEN v_number := r_test.transaction_amount;
                                WHEN  'L' THEN v_number := -r_test.transaction_amount;
                                WHEN  'EX' THEN v_number := r_test.transaction_amount;
                                WHEN  'RE' THEN v_number := -r_test.transaction_amount;
                                WHEN  'OE' THEN v_number := -r_test.transaction_amount;
                            END CASE;
                            UPDATE ACCOUNT
                            SET account_balance = account_balance + v_number
                            WHERE r_test.account_no = rec_account.account_no; 
                        ELSIF(r_test.transaction_type = 'C') THEN
                            v_credit_check := v_credit_check + r_test.transaction_amount;
                            CASE rec_account.account_type_code
                                WHEN  'A' THEN v_number := -r_test.transaction_amount;
                                WHEN  'L' THEN v_number := r_test.transaction_amount;
                                WHEN  'EX' THEN v_number := -r_test.transaction_amount;
                                WHEN  'RE' THEN v_number := r_test.transaction_amount;
                                WHEN  'OE' THEN v_number := r_test.transaction_amount;
                            END CASE;
                            UPDATE ACCOUNT
                            SET account_balance = account_balance + v_number
                            WHERE r_test.account_no = rec_account.account_no;
                        --ELSE
                            --ROLLBACK;
                            --INSERT INTO WKIS_ERROR_LOG(transaction_no, transaction_date, description, error_msg)
                            --VALUES (r_test.transaction_no, r_test.transaction_date, r_test.description, 'Not a Debit or a Credit');
                        END IF;

                        END lOOP;
            --IF(v_credit_check != v_debit_check) THEN
            --ROLLBACK;
            --INSERT INTO WKIS_ERROR_LOG(transaction_no, transaction_date, description, error_msg)
            --VALUES (r_transaction.transaction_no, r_transaction.transaction_date, r_transaction.description, 'Not a Debit or a Credit');
            --END IF;       


END LOOP;

END;
/
```

Comment: You've clearly commented out an `END` of some sort or a similar construct.  Just simplify, simplify, simplify and add back the code block by block.

Comment: I know it takes time but formatting a bit of code like this is well worth the time spent.  You have begins that do not line up under the declares, End loops that do not line up under your beginning of your loop missing indentation. Once formatted it quickly becomes clear that jayant Sahewal's answer below is correct and there is a missing end between the two end loops.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see END for your one of the BEGIN statements. You are missing END after your first END LOOP statement.

```
BEGIN
FOR r_test IN c_new_trans LOOP
                        ....
END LOOP;
END;
```